# How to get properties of object?

Tags: powershell

I have an issue where I am not able to get the properties from my variable `$filearray`. When I run `$filearray.gettype()` it comes back with `object` and `system.array`. the `$filearray` is set like this:

```
Directory                                Name
test                                     test
test2                                    test2
```

I want to be able to pull the name and directory as separate variables from this list and then be able to copy the path to the file and copy to a new destination.

```
function FindFiles {

    param(
        [string]$filestore
    )

    $length = $filestore.Length
    $GuidArray = @()

    for($line=0;$line -le $filestore.Count;$line++){

            $check = $filestore[$line]
            echo $check
            $length2 = $check.Length


            $fileGuid = $check | ForEach-Object{$_.FileGuid}





            $GuidArray = $GuidArray + $fileGuid    
    }

    write-host "-------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $filepath = Read-Host " Please Enter File Path to Search"

    for ($counter=0;$counter -lt $GuidArray.Count;$counter++){
        $fileArray = @()
        $guidcheck = $GuidArray[$counter]
        $file = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*$guidcheck*") } | Select-Object Directory,Name| Format-Table -AutoSize 
        $fileArray += $file
    }

    Write-Output $fileArray
    #for ($counter=0;$counter -lt $fileArray.Count;$counter++){

        #echo $fileArray[$counter]
        #$filetest = $fileArray[$counter] 
        #Copy-Item $filetest -Destination "C:\test"  
    #}
    return $Global:fileArray





}

function CopyFiles {

    param(
        [array]$fileArray
    )
    echo $fileArray

    echo $fileArray.GetType()


    $results = $fileArray | select -ExpandProperty Name
    echo $results

    #echo "hello"
    #for ($counter = 0;$counter -lt $fileArrray.Count;$counter++){
        #echo $fileArray[$counter]
        #$filetest = $fileArray[$counter]


        #Copy-Item 
    #}

}

function execute {
    $filestore = Import-Excel 'C:\594 Sample of Filestore.xlsx'
    echo $filestore

    #FindFiles($filestore)
    $fileArray = @(FindFiles($fileArray))
    echo "test"
    #echo "--------------------------------------------------------------"
    echo $fileArray
    #echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    #echo $fileArray.GetType()
    echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    CopyFiles($fileArray)
```

Comment: You've include a huge block of code, this isn't good practice as it's a lot to read through and it's not possible for us to be able to recreate your scenario as we do not know the inputs to your functions or have any of the files that you are using.

You should just include a concise block of code that should be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To be able to use Copy-Item you need a full path to the file and a destination like this: `Copy-Item "C:\folder\file.txt" -Destination "C:\Presentation"` Your `$filearray` doesn't contain this information so you cannot run this command.

Comment: the file array does contain the directory and filename but i cant call $filearray[0] to get the line. if I could just pull the strings from the variable i could copy the items but so far the array is printing data to the console but coming back as null when i try to access it in any other way except echo

Comment: I will just take a look at the importing of the excel and work my way back down from the beginning. Will report back results if interested

Comment: @goldenwest In the original `FindFiles()` function, you use `| Format-Table -AutoSize` when assigning your `$file` objects - remove this. (Also, blindly removing code from your question while still retaining references to the removed code is _not_ the same as putting together a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: what refrences to removed code are you referring to?

Comment: Nevermind. Have a look at the answer I posted (and remove that `Format-Table` statement)

Comment: ok trying now will report back results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the object imported by using import-excel i was able to call $filestore.FileGuid or whatever parameters you may have in you object and can build the array dynamically. This allowed me to store $filestore.fileguid in a new array like $guidArraywhich i was able to call using array spots like $GuidArray[0]

Answer (score 1):

As you've included so much code I cannot show exactly how you need to change it as there's jsut too much of it.

Here is simple example that shows how you would reference the `Directory` and `Name` properties of your `$filearray` in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($file in $filearray) {
    $file.Directory
    $file.Name
}
```

Comment: You would only like to see the $filearray code in question? I can edit the question to have less code i included it all because all the functions relate to one another and I figured without posting the whole thing you may not have enough information. Thank you for your comment !

Comment: @goldenwest check the mcve link and feel free to update your question and I'll be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: added the code in question and was still not able to get any output

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - you've still got a huge block of code that I cannot run.

Comment: I guess I am just a little confused at what you would like? without the entire code and the excel file present you wont be able to run the code uinless you have your own data set. I can shorten the code more but i dont see how that will help you run the ps1?

Comment: made short , if you would like it shorter let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `for` loop at the end of the `FindFiles` function (line breaks added by me):

```
for ($counter=0;$counter -lt $GuidArray.Count;$counter++){
    $fileArray = @()
    $guidcheck = $GuidArray[$counter]
    $file = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { 
        ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -like "*$guidcheck*") 
    } | Select-Object Directory,Name| Format-Table -AutoSize 
    $fileArray += $file               # ^
}                                     # |
                                      # This right here is your issue 
                                      # Format-Table will turn the output into 
                                      # machine-inspectable formatted text
```

Remove `Format-Table` from that pipeline.

You may still face some issues with your code, but at least you should be able to do `$fileArray[0].Name` now

Comment: that took away the structure of the $fileArray and made it so it only showed the names. However I was still unable to call $fileArray[0].Name with a successful result

Comment: What? You don't see a `Directory` and a `Name` NoteProperty if you do `$fileArray |Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty` after having removed `Format-Table`?

Comment: i do , thats the weird part but going echo $fileArray[0].Name doesnt print anything to the console

Comment: `$fileArray` may be just one file, try `@($fileArray)[0].Name`

Comment: If you are curious i ditched the whole filearray and was actually able to call $filestore.FileGuid to build a whole array dynamically off the orignal $filestore import

Comment: this gave me all the names of the files without having to run a foreach or for loop. Yes i am a dunce,